# O(n log n) algorithm with 10x input size

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

i have a problem with understanding this section of a book named : Computer science in distilled

[Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoYQl.png)

my problem is when it test O(n log n) with 10x input, the result i get from fraction of 10nlog(10n)/nlog(n) is 10 but the book says it's 34.
this is my solution

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x6Vh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is right. The book is wrong. If the running cost of an input of size `n` is `nlgn`, then increasing the input size by `T` (in your case `T=10`) will incur in a running cost of `Tnlg(Tn)`, giving a cost increase factor of `Tnlog(Tn)/(nlgn)`, which, as you pointed out, tends to `T` as `n → ∞`.

Note however that `lg2(1000) ≃ 10`. Therefore, `n` will have to be much greater than `1000` before you can neglect the `lg2(10)/lg2(n)` factor. So, in general, the increase factor will be `O(T)`, which is ok because we are dealing with big-O quantities from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

1. log2 10 ~ 3.4
2. log10 10 = 1

I think you are using log10 10, not log2 10 as from the book

Normally I think we just care about the big numbers(10 or 30 or 100), and probably use the exponent of 2(there are a lot of the algos that involves binary staff, so sometimes it is better use 2)

Comment: in the solution that i've used, log base doesn't matter. just used log laws...
it's true that log2 10 ~ 3.4 and 10 * 3.4 = 34. but my problem is how did the book get to 10 log (10) at the first place ... sorry for my poor english

Comment: I guess you don`t need to be sorry, it is no problem. as for the nlog(n), it is better you check the book, you should check merge sort, quick sort, and map and reduce, it is really useful when we can reduce the loops and probably make the impossible possible